# Second db connection in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

During a payment request, I want to insert addition information into the Magento database.  I want this additional information to be inserted **regardless** of the transaction result for the main database connection.

I believe the only  way to do this is to create a **second** connection to the database, as MySQL doesn't allow nested transactions.  How can create this second database connection in Magento OR is there another way to solve my problem?

Comment: What type of DB ? Where are you stuck exactly ? did you start anything ? ...

Comment: I've choosen already to use simpliest way - Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')

Comment: You need to clarify your need : do you need to access a new Database (different host/username/etc from the magento database) ? is it a mysql database ? what do you want exactly to do ?

Comment: I need second connection to the same db.

Answer (score 0):

$table = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($name);      Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write')->insert($table, $array);